# PHP: How to send file as the attachment without uploading to sever?

Tags: php, email

How to send file by `mail()` function of **PHP** as the attachment without uploading file to sever (just after *submiting* the form, using `$_FILES` array)?

Comment: If you want the server to send the file, it needs to be uploaded at some point.

Comment: @afuzzyllama, so i must to use move_uploaded_file() function and after sending the file, delete it?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the `$_FILES` array, the file is already uploaded to the server (usually in `/tmp`), so your question doesn't really make sense.

I understand what you mean, though. You want to send it as an attachment without moving it to a more permanent location. This can be done easily using
`file_get_contents($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']);`.

Answer (score 0):

get the file: $attachment = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];

get the file name: $attachment_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

add the file to mail: $mail->addAttachment($attachment,$attachment_name);